# Reuse Angular html view with different model each time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-material

I am currently developing an AngularJS application which offers a view with different sliders allowing a user to specify preferences in the `preferences.html` file (using Angular Material). Now I would like to extend this application to allow different users to use it at the same time. This means that `preferences.html` is displayed multiple times, one instance for each users. However, every time `preferences.html` is called, the preferences should be sent to another ng-model.

So far, my code looks like this (preference elicitation for a single user):

preferences.html:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as myCtrl">
  <div layout="row">
    <h2>One</h2>
    <md-slider class="preference-slider" min="0" step="1" max="20" ng-model="myCtrl.preferenceOne" id="slider"></md-slider>
    <p class="preference-value">{{myCtrl.preferenceOne}}</p>
    <h2>Two</h2>
    <md-slider class="preference-slider" min="0" step="1" max="20" ng-model="myCtrl.preferencesTwo" id="slider"></md-slider>
    <p class="preference-value">{{myCtrl.preferencesTwo}}</p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

myControler:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('myController', function($rootScope, $scope, $filter, $timeout) {
  this.PreferenceOne = 10;
  this.PreferenceTwo = 10;
  ...
});
```

The preferences Views for each user should de displayed simultaneously, like this:

```
<div ng-include="preferences.html" ng-show="isReady"></div> (for User 1)
<div ng-include="preferences.html" ng-show="isReady"></div> (for User 2)
...
```

Solutions to similar problems I found use directives but they always try to use only one View with multiple models. I, however, would like to have multiple instances of my view and each instance should use a different `ng-model`. Eventually I would like to collect the values of all models / views and send them to a backend.

Comment: bind each one to different route eg.. yourUrl/instance/1 and pass that route parameter to a controller. Each controller would be instanced from the same one only would have different url and thus with angular-ui-router form a different state. When reporting back, each one would pass said parameter as its indentificatior?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As far as I understand it correctly, UI-Router allows to  load only one state into an viewport. I would like to show multiple instances of the same html file multiple times at the same time (with different models). I updated my original post to illustrate that.

Comment: I am affraid so. You are gonna have to write custom overlord controller which will then either use static HTML or even dynamic if how many you will have at the same tyme is not static, which will then bind controllers as zerglings that overlord should produce. I would start with static html and 2 controllers active in it at the same time statically generated from overlord and try moving from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you used ui-router named views, and wired each one up to the same "preferences.html" templates and "preferencesController" or whatever, would that work? Is each instance essentially a single form, and the screen would allow multiple active users simultaneously (e.g. touch screen kiosk with single screen)?

```
<ui-view name="user1" />
<ui-view name="user2" />
etc.
```

Ultimately your requirement screams "MAKE ME INTO A DIRECTIVE", but if you want to do it this way for some reason, I understand. I too like to cut corners.

EDIT!

Try this:

```
$stateProvider      
  .state('multiUser',{      
    views: {        
      'user1': {        
        templateUrl: 'preferences.html',        
        controller: 'preferencesController'     
      },        
      'user2': {        
        templateUrl: 'preferences.html',        
        controller: 'preferencesController'     
      }     
    }       
  })
```

I've never done this personally, but I believe it instantiates a new instance of the controller for each named view, rather than "sharing" a single instance of the controller.

Comment: Yes, your example with the touch screen kiosk is exactly what I meant. I tried to get it working using angular-ui-router but I can't find a solution reusing the same html file for each user but storing the input in different variables.